# Best way to wait for input without blocking in synchronous code

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

In a WPF desktop app, I need to integrate with a third party API that takes a synchronous callback function. In this callback, I need to display a message provided by the third party software, wait for user input and then return that input to the third party software.

The interaction with the user will be in my main window (not a modal dialog), so the UI thread must not be blocked while in the callback function.

There are a number of ways to do this: threads & AutoResetEvent, DispatcherTimer, etc. But most articles describing these methods were written before the async features of .Net 4.5 were available. Nowadays, is there any reason to do anything more complex than the following?

```
        {
            ...
            // Call 3rd party code passing our callback function
            thirdParty.Process(referenceNumber, amount, GetValue))
            ...
        }

        // UI sets this variable from the user's input
        private string _getValueResponse = null;

        // The callback function passed to third party API
        private void GetValue(ref ClientInstruction clientInstruction)
        {
            var message = clientInstruction.Message;
            _getValueResponse = null;
            // This event passes the 3rd party message to my main window,
            // and causes it to prompt for user input.
            GetValueRequired?.Invoke(this, new GetValueRequiredEventArgs(message));

            var result = Task.Run<string>(
                async () => await WaitForGetValueResponse())
                .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            // Return user input to the third party code
            clientInstruction.EnteredValue = result;
        }

        private async Task<string> WaitForGetValueResponse()
        {
            while (_getValueResponse == null)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }

            return _getValueResponse;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need wait? What's GetValueRequired.

Comment: `GetValue()` will block if you do it like that...

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I think it only blocks a thread pool thread, rather than the UI, doesn't it? I haven't had a problem with it blocking yet - in what circumstances do you think it will?

Comment: @davidl It blocks the callback thread. Your UI thread is still free assuming they're not the same thread.

Comment: @davidl Where you call `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` the caller will block until `GetResult()` returns, which won't happen until the underlying task completes.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `BeginRead` like pattern as below

```
Task.Run(() => thirdParty.Process(referenceNumber, amount, GetValue)))
  .ContinueWith();
```

`Task.Run` will start new thread to get user input and return control back immediately.
And `GetValue` must be blocking call since third party software does not expect it async, is't it?

`ContinueWith()` must be populated with logic that processes user inputs and returns it back to your model

However I'm not sure that this is good. First problem is that `Task.Run` spawn new thread and UI dialog can fail to be shown properly. However you can handle it with dispatcher in WPF.

I suppose that waiting for user input should be `blocking call` and there is not too much benefit with non-blocking input.

You are using third party software and writing `async GetValue` will not work.

What would you like to achieve when saying "non-blocking user input in this case" ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've edited the question to try and clarify what I mean about not blocking - basically I need to show a message provided by the 3rd party and accept user input, both in my main window, so the UI thread must not be blocked. I think your suggestion converts to async a bit too far out so doesn't seem to do what I need.

Comment: [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) will not start a new thread necessarily. It will use an already started thread from the `ThreadPool`. The `ThreadPool` will create a new thread only if it's starved, and only after a delay of 500 msec.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias well, I'm getting new thread (non UI). Is it a big difference was it started or taken from pool ?

Comment: No, it's not a big difference. The `ThreadPool` threads are reused for efficiency, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You are spinning up another thread just to await a result.

To be clear, there are three threads at play here.

- Your UI thread
- The thread that called your callback
- A thread that you spin up with Task.Run()

This third thread is pointless, since all it does is sit and await a result from the UI thread, and the second thread sits and waits for the third thread!

If you are happy for the callback to block while you wait (which you current code does), why not just Sleep?

```
    private void GetValue(ref ClientInstruction clientInstruction)
    {
        var message = clientInstruction.Message;
        _getValueResponse = null;

        // This event causes the UI to prompt for input
        GetValueRequired?.Invoke(this, new GetValueRequiredEventArgs(message));

        //poll for response
        while (_getValueResponse == null)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        clientInstruction.EnteredValue = _getValueResponse ;
    }
```

However, this feels wrong to me. I doubt your third party API is expecting you to lock its callback thread, especially as it provides you with a context object to set the result?

Can you not just store the `ClientInstruction` in a member and set it directly from the UI thread?

Comment: But, unless the third party code is doing something clever (and I don't think it is very sophisticated!), surely "the thread that called your callback" is likely to be the same one that I called the 3rd party code on? And in case that is my UI thread, I'm trying to do the waiting on a thread pool thread instead of the original.

Comment: It cannot be the UI thread since the callback thread will block on GetResult(), which would result in deadlock.